# T-SQL - XML TAG DESCRIPTION + VALUE

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I can't receive XML in this format:

```
<ROOT>
    <Test ColA="A">B</Test>
</ROOT>
```

This what I have:

```
select 'A' as ColumnA, 'B' as ColumnB into _Atest
```

```
select ColumnA as [Test/@A]
from _Atest
for XML PATH (''), root ('ROOT')
```

And output are:

```
<ROOT>
  <Test A="A" />
</ROOT>
```

How I can receive:

```
<ROOT>
    <Test ColA="A">B</Test>
</ROOT>
```

"A" - value from ColumnA
B - value from ColumnB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ColumnA CHAR(1), ColumnB CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @tbl (ColumnA, ColumnB) VALUES
('A', 'B');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ColumnA AS [Test/@ColA]
    , ColumnB AS [Test]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('ROOT');
```

**Output**

```
<ROOT>
  <Test ColA="A">B</Test>
</ROOT>
```